# Как сохранить (сериализовать) все свойства button'a?

Tags: c#

Как сохранить (сериализовать) все свойства button'a (расположение, цвет, шрифт), чтобы при выходе и обратном открытии формы все сохранилось... пожалуйста, ответьте! Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Если свойства, которые нужно сохранять, заранее известны, то можно при выходе из приложения сохранять их в Properties.Settings.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.buttonColor = button.BackColor;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Если же свойства неизвестны, можно их попробовать пронумеровать

```
IDictionary<String, String> = button.GetType()
  .GetProperties()
  .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.PropertyType == typeof(String))
  .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => (String) p.GetValue(myObject, null));
```

Answer (score 1):

Интересный функционал, зачем мне в программе возможность настроить цвет одной кнопки или всех, но по разному?, логичнее было бы предложить темы, тогда не надо хранить состояние отдельных элементов - достаточно тему по умолчанию.

Можно воспользоваться способом [[@Василий](/users/31/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9)](/users/31/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Можно сериализовать в JSON или воспользоваться стандартной сериализацией...

```
[Serializable]
    class MyButton:Button, ISerializable
    {
        public MyButton()
            : base()
        {
        }

        protected MyButton(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context):base()
        {
            this.Text = info.GetString("Text");
            this.Location = (Point)info.GetValue("Location",typeof(Point));
        }

        [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, 
        SerializationFormatter =true)]
        public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("Text", this.Text);
            info.AddValue("Location", this.Location);
        }

    }
```